# How to add the 1st column data of each line to the head of each column marked by some specific string or characters in the conresponding line?

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a big chunk of data (one file) as following, each line has different number of columns(delimited by tab), the data structure like 
this :

```
>NP_12345.1 matchnumber_1_RKHKK 
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_1_HGRR  matchnumber_2_KQRHH  matchnumber_3_RVRK matchnumber_4_HTHH
>XP_543421.1    matchnumber_1_RQRH  ... matchnumber_m_RVRR
...
```

In the file above, the 1st line has 2 columns, the 2nd line has 5 columns, and the 3rd line has m+1 columns...; Obviously, each line of the file have ">accessionID" and "matchnumber_i_XXX". I want to add the 1st column of each line to the head of each column marked by "matchnumber" in the conresponding line, and print out as fasta format, the output is just like this:

```
>NP_12345.1matchnumber_1
RKHKK   
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_1
HGRR    
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_2
KQRHH
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_3
RVRK
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_4
HTHH
>XP_543421.1matchnumber_1
RQRH
....
>XP_543421.1matchnumber_m
RVRR
...
```

Anyone could help me ? Thanks in advance.

Note: When there is an one line file, for example, the file "a.txt" has the only one line content:

```
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_1_HGRR  matchnumber_2_KQRHH  matchnumber_3_RVRK matchnumber_4_HTHH
```

I can use piped awk and sed commands to parse the data:

```
cat a.txt |awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1$2,$1$3,$1$4,$1$5}' | sed 's/\t/\n/g' | sed 's/_/ /g' | sed 's/NP /NP_/g' | sed 's/matchnumber /matchnumber_/g' | sed 's/ /\n/g' > a.fasta
```

The a.fasta is as the fowlloing:

```
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_1
HGRR
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_2
KQRHH
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_3
RVRK
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_4
HTHH
```

When a.txt has multiple lines of that data, I have no idea to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [`gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) (for the [`gensub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) extenstion) might work for you:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1 gensub(/_([^_]+)$/,"\n\\1",1,$i)}}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat jfile
>NP_12345.1     matchnumber_1_RKHKK
>NP_56789.2     matchnumber_1_HGRR      matchnumber_2_KQRHH     matchnumber_3_RVRK      matchnumber_4_HTHH

$ awk -F"\t" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){match($i,"(matchnumber_[0-9]+)_(.*)",r);print $1 r[1] ORS r[2];}}' jfile
>NP_12345.1matchnumber_1
RKHKK
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_1
HGRR
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_2
KQRHH
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_3
RVRK
>NP_56789.2matchnumber_4
HTHH
```

Loop from the second field `$2` to last field `$NF`, use `match` and `regex` to take out things you wanted, eg `matchnumber_1` and `RKHKK` for first one, and print.

In awk space is just for concatenate, `ORS` means line ending, effectively equals `\n` here. `r` is the regex matched array, with r[0] represent the whole matched string, r[1] and r[2] represent the first and second pair of `()` matched contents. -- You can change `r` to other variable name you want.

As for the regex, [0-9] means any single number, and the `+` after that means to match 1 or more afore denoted thing, here means 1 or more consecutive number(s). As above mentioned, parentheses are just there to catch contents to groups, for later reference. Each pair of parentheses matched contents will be saved into the one element of the array I provided, which is `r` here.

Comment: thanks a lot, when the data is more complicated, such as:      >NP_12345.1 matchnumber_1_starto=17~21_RKHKK                 
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_1_starto=26~29_HGRR  matchnumber_2_starto=98~102_KQRHH  matchnumber_3_starto=108~112_RVRK matchnumber_4_starto=123~126_HTHH, I rewrite your code as "awk -F"\t" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){match($i,"(matchnumber_[0-9]+)_(starto=[0-9]+~[0-9]+)_(.*)",r);print $1 r[1] r[2] ORS r[3];}}' ", it worked very well ! Very appreciate !

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
$ cat james.txt
>NP_12345.1 matchnumber_1_RKHKK
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_1_HGRR  matchnumber_2_KQRHH  matchnumber_3_RVRK matchnumber_4_HTHH
>XP_543421.1    matchnumber_1_RQRH matchnumber_2_QQQQ
$ perl -lne ' /(^\S+) (.+)/;$pre=$1;$mat=$2;while($mat=~/(match.+?_\d+)_(\S+)/g) { print "$pre $1\n$2" } ' james.txt
>NP_12345.1 matchnumber_1
RKHKK
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_1
HGRR
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_2
KQRHH
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_3
RVRK
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_4
HTHH
>XP_543421.1 matchnumber_1
RQRH
>XP_543421.1 matchnumber_2
QQQQ
$
```

Explanation

```
perl -lne  
# -l to remove newline when reading and add newline when print statement is used
# -n - suppress default printing at the end of each line processing
# -e - for perl on commandline

' /(^\S+) (.+)/;
split line by first word (^\S+) -> matches first column and stores it in $1 since we used () to capture
the second (.+) stores the rest of the text in $2 

$pre=$1;$mat=$2; 

Assign $1 to $pre and $2 to $mat

while($mat=~/(match.+?_\d+)_(\S+)/g) 
Now mat stores from 2nd column to the rest of the line.
// => match with regex and (match.+?_\d+) to capture it in $1
(\S+) => captures the "HGRR"
/g => like this we have many matches.. so 'g'lobally repeat the matching 
to get all of them using the while loop. If /g is ignored, then we will just get first match alone.

 { print "$pre $1\n$2" } 
Now print $pre, $1 newline and $2 --> This $1 and $2 is local to the while loop and 
don't get confused with the earlier $1 and $2 which we assigned to $pre and $mat
for each while loop turn $1 and $2 match different values and get printed.
```

Comment: glad that it worked fast!.. I'll add explanation to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Another perl one liner:

```
perl -anE '($c1,@r)=split/\s+/,$_;for(@r){($c,$v)=$_=~/^(.+)_(.+)$/;say "$c1 $c\n$v"}' file.txt
>NP_12345.1 matchnumber_1
RKHKK
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_1
HGRR
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_2
KQRHH
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_3
RVRK
>NP_56789.2 matchnumber_4
HTHH
>XP_543421.1 matchnumber_1
RQRH
>XP_543421.1 matchnumber_2
RQRH
>XP_543421.1 matchnumber_3
RQRH
```

**Explanation:**

```
($c1,@r)=split/\s+/,$_;             # split allline into 1 col value and rest of the line
for(@r){                            # for each lols othar than 1rst one
    ($c,$v)=$_=~/^(.+)_(.+)$/;      # extract before the last underscore and after it
    say "$c1 $c\n$v"                # print col1 coln linebreak value
}
```

Comment: can be shortened ````perl -anE '($c1,@r)=split/\s+/; m/^(.+)_(.+)$/ and say "$c1 $1\n$2" for(@r) '````

Comment: @stack0114106: True.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not good at one line commands but it is easy to parse your file with it:

parser.py:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():     # process stdin or files given as parameters
    words = line.split()           # split the line
    for w in words[1:]:            # process all words past the first
        ix = w.rindex('_')         # search last _ in the words
        print(words[0] + w[:ix])   # print first line
        print(w[ix+1:])            # and second one
```

You can then use either:

```
cat file | python parse.py
```

or:

```
python parse.py file
```

Comment: I use: python parse.py file > output, to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;h;/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)_(\S+)\s*(.*)/{s//\1\2\n\3/p;x;s//\1 \4/;ta};d' file
```

Make a copy of the current line. Use pattern matching to manipulate the first and second fields in the pattern space to the required format and print it. Swap to the copy and shorten it by removing the second field and any following white space. Repeat until pattern matching fails.